# ¿Por que me sale error al imprimir mi arreglo?

Tags: java

```
package librerias;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LenteContacto {
   private static Scanner in;

public static void main(String args[]) {
       in = new Scanner(System.in);

       int[ ] n = new int[5];
       int[ ] ward = new int[5];
       int[ ] del = new int[5];
       int j;
       int i;


          for( i=0; i<5; i++) {
              System.out.println("Ingrese el numero");
              n[i] = in.nextInt();
              del[i] = 0;
              ward[i] = 0;

          } 

          for( i=0; i<5; i++) {
               if(del[i] != 2) {
                   for( j=0; j<5; j++) {
                       if(j != i) {
                           if(n[i] == n[j]) {
                               ward[i] = ward[i]+1;
                               del[j] = 2;
                           }

                       }
                   }
               }

          }


          System.out.println(ward[i]);



  }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Estas tratando de acceder a ward[5] y tu arreglo solo llega hasta ward[4].
Esto pasa debido a que después del for el i se queda con valor 5 por el mismo incremento del for.

Comment: Es la respuesta, pero podrias explicar un poco mas para que se entienda mejor

Answer (score 0):

Cuando hagas una impresion de arreglos, todo debe de hacerse dentro del arreglo o te dara error porque no lo estas iterando de forma correcta.

```
for( i=0; i<5; i++) {
   System.out.println(ward[i]);
}
```

Borre tus variables del y ward ya que dentro del primer ciclo estas igualandolas a 0 y no tiene sentido pero con este ejemplo podras darte cuenta de donde estaba tu error y como se imprime un arreglo y ya si necesitas las variables que quite solo es cuestion de volverlas a agregar.